# datatable: add observations to all groups and assign value that depends on other rows

Tags: r, data.table, data-management

Assume that we have a data.table with ids and subgroups as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(id=c("A","A","B","B"), subgroup=c("k","m","k","m"), C=c(4,9,6,5))
> DT
   id subgroup C
1:  A        k 4
2:  A        m 9
3:  B        k 6
4:  B        m 5
```

Now we want to introduce new subgroups to each id, which value C depends on another subgroup. In this example the *new* subgroup *l* should be 0.5 of subgroup *k*, for a given id:

```
   id subgroup C
1:  A        k 4
2:  A        l 2
3:  A        m 9
4:  B        k 6
5:  B        l 3
6:  B        m 5
```

How could one achieve this efficiently using data.table? The only solution I have come up with is reshaping to wide and then creating new columns; but if one has a large set of ids, this would be fairly clumsy.

Note: in a real-life application there would be many more subgroups and ids.

**UPDATED TO TAKE INTO ACCOUNT COMPLEX CASE OF HAVING MORE THAN 2 SUBGROUPS**

Comment: Perhaps you could add a second subgroup in the starting example to make sure you get an answer that can handle the complexity of your real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
# add a new row in each group based on given condition
DT <- rbind(DT, DT[,.SD,id][,`:=`(subgroup = 'l', C = C/2)])

# order the data by id
DT <- DT[order(id)]
```

Alternate format as suggested by @Frank:

```
DT[, rbind(.SD, copy(.SD)[,`:=`(subgroup = 'l', C = C/2)])]
setorder(res, id)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if there are more than 2 subgroups this would not work, right? The C/2 would have to be conditioned on subgroup k somehow.

Comment: You can use `copy(.SD)` instead of `DT[,.SD,id]`. @Luks You can use `.SD[subgroup == "k"]` there, yeah.

Comment: @Frank sorry but i don't understand, could you explain bit more?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `res = DT[, rbind(.SD, copy(.SD)[,\`:=\`(subgroup = 'l', C = C/2)])]; setorder(res, id)` (just another way of doing what you have already). And for Luks' extension `res = DT[, rbind(.SD, .SD[subgroup == "k"][,\`:=\`(subgroup = 'l', C = C/2)])]; setorder(res, id)` (Overwriting with `DT <- f(DT)` makes the example somewhat hard to follow for me, btw.)